# I am trying to remove my widgets using grid_forget but it is not working

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to remove my widgets by using grid_forget which i had used previously in my code and worked fine but in this part it does not work

```
from tkinter import*
def hfmenureturn():
    hotfood.grid_forget()
def hotfood():
    hf.grid_forget()
    hotfoodhome = Button(order, text = 'Home', bg = 'white', fg = 'black', 
    font = 'arial 20 bold', command = hfmenureturn)
    hotfoodhome.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
order = Tk()
hf = Button (order, text = 'HOT FOOD', bg = 'red2', fg = 'black', font = 
'arial 15', width = 43, height = 7, command = hotfood)
hf.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W)

order.mainloop()
```

the error message that pops up is AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'grid_forget'

Comment: As the error clearly states, in `hotfood.grid_forget()` - `hotfoot` is a function. You can't call `grid_forget` on a func.

Comment: It says the same thing when i try to use the name of the widget but that doesnt work either and the error i get is NameError: name 'hotfoodhome' is not defined

Comment: `hotfoodhome` is a widget within the local scope of your function `hotfood`. What you need is some means to pass a variable from one function to another, e.g. by declaring `global`, or append to a global container.